# Update tab content using firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create an Firefox addon which gives hyper link to phone numbers on a page.
Code:

```
  tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  tab.attach({
  contentScript: 'self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML);',
  onMessage: function (message) {
  html = updatePhonenumber(message);      
  }
 });
});
```

how to update the content of tab with edited content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve that is using a [PageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) which according to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) "run scripts in the context of web pages whose URL matches a given pattern".

So, you will have two files:

**lib/main.js**:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*", // <- this tell firefox to attach the following
                //    content script to all web pages
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url("phone-detector.js")
});
```

**data/phone-detector.js**:

```
/* This is a normal js file that gets attached to the current web page
and has access to the DOM*/
var updatePhonenumber = function(dom) {
   // do whatever you should do
}:

updatePhonenumber(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like `function(tab)` is returning a tab element. try going `console.log(tab.linkedBrowser)` if you see a non `null` message in browser console then go `tab.linkedBrowser.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = 'rawr'` this is just an example how to change the document, you shouldnt use innerHTML, should create element and append it or remove elements.